# Jruby Stack Traces

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jruby

So this might be a dumb question but I don't know what to ask for since 'jruby print stack trace' googled doesn't come up with much thats worthwhile but,

How does one print the stack trace when writing Jruby code that accesses Java classes that throw exceptions? ie right now I took code from someone else that looks like

`rescue JavaSql::SQLException
  puts "SQLException"
end`

which works, but I'd like to see which particular SQLException is happening like I would in Java (ie. PrintStackTrace(Exception e))?  How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never worked with Java exceptions in Ruby, but AFAIK, Java exceptions get presented to you as Ruby exceptions, which means you can get the exception message by sending the `:message` message to the exception object:

```
begin
  # stuff
rescue JavaSql::SQLException => e
  puts "#{e.class}: #{e.message}"
end
```

Is that what you mean? I'm not quite sure what you would need the stacktrace for in this particular situation, so I probably misunderstood.

Comment: oops, yeah thats exactly what I meant.  Thanks a lot!  I'm kind of new to how Jruby and Java interact with eachother.

Answer (score 0):

One would imagine it relies on the underlying implementation.  If the underlying implementation just swallows the exception you will not be able to see a stack trace.  Also why don't you just allow the exception to bubble up in your ruby code so that the trace gets thrown out to the screen?